# ARSoft.Tools.Net.Dns "Response records could not be validated" TLSA

Tags: exception, dns, resolve, arsoft.tools.net

Using the code below to validate DANE records on different mail servers i sometimes (close to 50% of the servers tested) get a "System.AggregateException" with the inner exception "Response records could not be validated".

```
var resolver = new SelfValidatingInternalDnsSecStubResolver();
        string mx = "mail2.amedia.nu.";
        DnsSecResult<TlsaRecord> result = resolver.ResolveSecure<TlsaRecord>("_25._tcp." + mx, RecordType.Tlsa);
        Console.WriteLine(result.ValidationResult.ToString());
```

I pasted the first 1000 failed mx servers here for testing: https://pastebin.com/14kqQT06

Any idea why this exception is thrown?

Comment: Give one and only one example to reproduce. Maybe no DNSSEC, so no validation? DNSSEC is mandatory for DANE.

Comment: I wanted to give a few extra as someone might be able to see a pattern in them. The "mail2.amedia.nu" does not support DNSSEC but shouldn't that give a ValidationResult.Unsigned instead of just throwing an exception?